# scala - mimic unix style printing of variables

Tags: scala

I have the below shell script function which prints the variable name as well as the value.

```
function print_variables {
  for v in $*
  do
  v2=$(eval echo "$"$v)
  echo "$v=$v2"
  done
}

c1=100
c2=200
c3=500

print_variables c1 c2 c3
```

output

```
c1=100
c2=200
c3=500
```

I'm trying the same functionality in scala, but not getting the above results

```
def print_vars(names:String*)= {
  for(name <- names) {
    println(name /*some_code*/)
  }
}

val c1 = 100
val c2 = 200
val c3 = 500

print_vars("c1","c2", "c3")
```

This just prints c1, c2, c3.. but what should be inserted in the /*some_code*/ to get the output as c1=100, etc?.

Answer (score 1):

Getting variable names at runtime is not possible out of the box because JVM doesn't offer any such handle by default. Below is a naive implementation of the requirement

```
def print_vars(names:(String,Int)*)= {
  for(name <- names) {
    println(name._1 +" = " + name._2)
  }
}

val c1 = ("c1",100)
val c2 = ("c2",200)
val c3 = ("c3",500)

scala> print_vars(c1,c2,c3)
c1 = 100
c2 = 200
c3 = 500
```

If open to using custom libraries then [name-of](https://github.com/dwickern/scala-nameof) can be used to achieve this as shown below

```
import com.github.dwickern.macros.NameOf._

val c1 = 100
val c2 = 200
val c3 = 300

def print_vars (variableName:String, value:Int) = {
    println(variableName + " = " + value)
}

print_vars (nameOf(c1),c1)
print_vars (nameOf(c2),c2)
print_vars (nameOf(c3),c3)
```